# eloquent modifying variable without overwriting

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to perform some queries using a set variable with models inside it

so what I'm trying to do is something like this

```
$orders = (new Order)->where('placed_by', '=', "client");
```

if you die and dump this the outcome would be as expected now

let's find something specific

```
$totalPrice = $orders->where('total_price', '=', "100");
```

and then find something else

```
$totalPrice = $orders->where('total_price', '=', "10");
```

what you would think that the $orders variable contents would stay static but it doesn't it changes now is there a way to keep it as is without it changing because of the next operations?

Comment: Hello Bro, you can use clone provided by laravel. if it solves your problem then give me like

Answer (score 0):

[mofiroz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195545/mofiroz) suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160468/eloquent-modifying-variable-without-overwriting/72162738#comment127497513_72160468) :

> you can use clone provided by laravel.

which works.